# Create a data type Enum in MS Acces

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a db but i wanted to create a "enum" type,Like sql,

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
name VARCHAR(40),
size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
```

);

but i couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: In Access, that is called _Lookup_ fields. You may need DAO to create such fields from code. However, this is a "user type" feature; as a programmer, you should refrain from these and create a table to hold the sizes.

Comment: Whether list is from table or string, advise not to set up in table, just build comboboxes or listboxes on forms. Especially if lookup has alias, which yours does not but still don't think setting this up in table is worth effort.

Answer (score 0):

First, you mean MySQL - not a feature of SQL server.

As noted, all this really is a table, say like this:

[image]

Builing such a emum does not help all that much, but it is just a table. I find it is MUCH MUCH MUCH MUCH better to just create a table like above, and use a correct good solid relatonal desing in your software.

The above table can drive any combo box for data entry in a form in which you pick a value.

However, you CAN create a lookup in Access.

Just read this first:

***The evils of lookups:***

http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm

So what MySQL and a few vendors have done? Well, they kind of think they are saving you time - but in the long run? You will not!!!

But you can do this:

[image]

And then enter a list of choices. I don't recommend ENUM's in a database, and Access had that feature for 20+ years - and it is a bad idea.

Build your pick lists as a simple standard table. Then when creating a access form, drop in a combo box, and use the wizard against that table - it takes about 3 mouse clicks.

Being able to just drop a field as enum onto a form might save you 40 seconds to setup that pick list on a form, but you LOSE OUT VERY badly in the long run - don't do it!!!